# Undefined method role for Cancan in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, cancan

Currently I'm implementing a simple demo for a school management system. After I login I get the following exception:

```
undefined method `role' for nil:NilClass
app/models/ability.rb:5:in `initialize'
app/controllers/application_controller.rb:10:in `new'
app/controllers/application_controller.rb:10:in `current_ability'
```

Here's `ability.rb`:

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability
  def initialize(user)
    if user.role.name=='admin'
      can :manage, :all
    end

    if user.role.name=='teacher'
      can :read, Course
    end
  end
end
```

Here's `application_controller.rb`:

```
def set_current_user(user)
    @current_user=user
end

def current_ability
  @current_ability||= Ability.new(current_user)
end

def current_user
  @current_user
end
```

I authenticate the user in the `users_controller.rb` as:

```
def authenticate
  @user=User.find_by_name_and_password(params[:name],params[:password])

    if @user
      set_current_user(@user)
      respond_to do |format|
       format.html { redirect_to courses_path }
       format.json { head :no_content }
      end
    end
 end
```

finally here you are the method index in courses_controllers.rb, it's very simple as you can see

```
class CoursesController < ApplicationController
  load_and_authorize_resource
  def index
   @courses = Course.all

   respond_to do |format|
     format.html # index.html.erb
     format.json { render json: @courses }
   end
  end
 end
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Looks like you're not passing any value in the `user` argument. Can you elaborate on whether the `authenticate` method works as required?

Comment: @RichPeck actually the initialize method in ability.rb is called implicitly and I can not either adjust the user parameter to be sent correctly by the current user nor making it to be called one time explicitly, if you can help me this would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Nice! I love when someone knows more than me :) What I was suggesting is you're passing `current_user` to your `Ability.new` object. I think the problem will be your `current_user` object won't be populated, hence why I was asking about your `authenticate` method. If that doesn't work, how can you pass a `user` object?

Comment: @RichPeck The authenticate method is working fine but the problem is the Ability.new is called implicitly (without invoking it) and the user is set to nil in this case, as you can see I'm not calling current_ability in my code, when I call it explicitly the method is executed two times (one with implicit invocation and another with an explicit invocation)

Comment: Okay, so when is `Ability.new` is invoked implicitly? I'm leaning here - so please forgive me if I ask noob questions ^_^

Comment: @RichPeck great that we've two noobs digging with each other:D , actually I'm a new to the cancan authorization gem, this behavior is occurring due to some magic within this gem :)

Comment: Sure - the gem will fire in the background, but I'm wondering why it creates / overrides your setting of the `user` object? Surely if you pass the `user` to the gem, it will just use the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error tells you that "current_user" is nil, and this is the case.

I assume that you authenticate users and then redirect them to `courses_path`, and it's all fine because you actually assign an instance of `User` to `current_user`. However, after the redirect it doesn't know about user and seems like session is not created.

I'd recommend you to assign `session[:user_id]` in `authenticate`, therefore you will be able to allow `current_user` return an instance of user during the session.

Also, you might just use Devise to handle all this logic for you.

Comment: I think that I don't have to use Devise and sessions as I'm developing a very simple model for authorization, so there no need to make the code complicated